# I am not able to install curl package on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, curl

I am trying to install meteor using : `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`
command on terminal but it gives me following error:

```
 The program 'curl' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
 sudo apt-get install curl
```

And when I tried installing curl by command : `sudo apt-get install curl`
Following error is shown to me:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source

 E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259681/the-program-curl-is-currently-not-installed) on askubuntu.

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/us.archive.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Answer (score -1):

hook up to the best server from the software & updates section
then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). When adding answers to older questions with existing answers it is useful to explain what new information your answer has that the existing ones don't have.